# Turn JSON schema into type-safe object

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

I have a string that is a (valid) definition of a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html). I want to iterate over that schema to create a form.

How do I turn that string into a type-safe object that I can start working with?

Most libraries I find are about validating some kind of input against a JSON schema, for example [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) ...but I'm stuck figuring out a smart approach of using these libraries to my advantage. I would like to avoid having to write the full type definition of a json schema.

Comment: "create a form" - https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. In case I want to build something myself, how would I go about creating a type-safe object of my schema? That seems to be the starting point?

Comment: I've seen that library used with zod. - https://zod.dev/?id=basic-usage